# Moodle - new (not customized) translations

Tags: php, moodle

I created some additional webpages (php files) in Moodle. They're accessible of course from the appropriate path (e.g. "..my_folder/page.php").

Now I'm trying to find a solution for adding new translation entries. I noticed that I can edit existing translations in e.g. "[moodledata]/lang/[language-code]/[filename].php" files, however adding new files, or even adding new string to the existing files, has no any effect. After clearing a cache they still seem to be "invisible" for Moodle. I don't know how it works, it must be quite complicated?

**How can I add new (not modify old) translation strings for Moodle?** Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Create a lang folder for your plugin.

eg: if you are creating a local plugin then use

```
/local/yourpluginname/lang/en/local_yourpluginname.php
```

if its a block then

```
/block/yourblockname/lang/en/block_yourblockname.php
```

etc.

Then in the file have

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

$string['pluginname'] = 'yourpluginname';
$string['yourstringid'] = 'String you want to display';
```

Then call using

```
echo get_string('yourstringid', 'local_yourpluginname');
```

For more information see 
http://docs.moodle.org/dev/String_API

EDIT :

Nothing wrong with having traditional php pages :)

You should use the local directory for any non-standard plugins - eg:

```
/local/mypages/mypage1.php
/local/mypages/mypage2.php
/local/mypages/lang/en/local_mypages.php
```

Then call directly with

```
echo html_writer::link(new moodle_url('/local/mypages/mypage1.php), 
     get_string('mypage1title', 'local_mypages');
```

Have a look at a typical structure in

```
/local/readme.txt
```

To use the get_strings, you'll need to include the config file at the top of mypage1.php etc.

```
require_once(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . '/config.php');
```

Comment: Thanks. But I didn't write any plugin, I just created pages (php files in an old-fashion way, i.e. being directly pages available at the same path where they were placed, without mvc etc.). Can I still use moodle translations in a "moodle"-like way then? Or I'm stuck with my own solution only in this case?

Comment: Nothing wrong with traditional pages :) I've updated my answer.